# What happens if I change the ProductID of an already existing WP app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1.1

I have two applications already submitted to the marketplace and just now I realized that they have the same ProductIDs in the WMAppManifest and AssemblyInfo files - so I can not have both of the apps installed (deployed) to the emulator at the same time.

If during the submission process this ProductID remains the same, then I am afraid that users will not be able to install both of my apps at once. So I guess my question is: does it really matter what ProductID I specify in those two files? or does the submission process take care of it and generates a truly unique GUID?

Comment: Isn't this a question more suited for Microsoft support?

Comment: Don't really think so. Plus, this way the question and answer are visible for other persons that have the same problem I have.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The product Id is assigned when you create the app in the app hub. For WP7.X especially, most of what you put in the WMManifest.xml is over/re-written as part of the certification process.

The bigger issue you are likely to hit is that you can't load multiple apps on a device with the same ProductId so if you ever want to load them in the same emulator instance or on the same physical device you'll need to change one of them.

Comment: Are there any things I need to do/remeber when changing productId or can I just change random character in it to other value?

Comment: @Skiba as long as you keep it a valid GUID then you should be fine to change random characters as necessary

Comment: @Skiba I usually create a new windows phone app and copy that GUID to my app. Just to be sure.

Comment: @MariusBughiu The same idea hit my mind after reading your first answer. Went that way, looks like it works.