# Are package/product IDs mandatory in WMAppManifest.xml?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, manifest

I need to create an application for another company. Therefore, I won't submit the app directly, but need to let the company customize it and submit it itself.

I heard that some attributes of the WMAppManifest.xml file are replaced automatically by the web submission interface, and others are not. What is the state of the following ones (it's never mentioned in Microsoft resources):

- ProductID
- Author
- Publisher
- PublisherID

Can I let the values generated by Visual Studio in the manifest (then I assume they will be overridden by the web submission interface), or must I ask my customer its own values for these fields?

Comment: Maybe Author or Publisher gets overwritten based on the registered PublisherID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values of **ProductID**, **Author**, **Publisher** and **PublisherID** are only relevant for local testing and are overridden when submitting your app to the Windows Phone store...

1. [A previous answer regarding Windows Phone 7 and the WMAppManifest.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14486656/247257)
2. [Windows Phone 8 and the new PublisherID](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/7e265aed-1719-4158-bc98-5d985e694c4c/)

Comment: Thanks, your links are very valuable!

Answer (score 0):

If the other company makes the final build then it would make sense to obtain these values initially from them, so when you exchange code the data remains constant.